# Отсеять все значения None из Json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, строки

Задача: получить большой Json и из него выдернуть несколько десятков нужных значений. Далее эти значения запихнуть в строку вида:

```
result = 'Директор: ' + str(json['person1']['name']) + ', Заместитель: ' + str(json['person2']['name']) + ', Бухгалтер: ' итд
```

для отправки в мессенджер в виде get-запроса.
Все работает хорошо, но иногда некоторые значения name = None.
Как мне в дзене Python отсеять все None значения и соответственно чтобы в конечную переменную result не попадали не только сами None, но и убирались соответствующие должности? Например если у заместителя нет имени, то и в итоговую строку просто эта должность не попадала вообще, и было так:

```
result = 'Директор: ' + str(json['person1']['name']) + ', Бухгалтер: ' итд
```

На ум приходит только монструозная конструкция (учитывая что должностей- несколько десятков) проверок if-else, но думаю есть путь проще

Comment: `_json.get('person2').get('name')`?

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так:

```
POSITIONS_CONFIG = {
  "Директор": "person1",
  "Заместитель": "person2",
  "Бухгалтер": "person3",
}

positions = []
for title, pos_json_key in POSITIONS_CONFIG.items():
   name = json[pos_json_key]['name']
   if name:
        positions.add(f"{title}: {name}")
result = ', '.join(positions)
```

Comment: `json[pos_json_key]['name']` -> `json[pos_json_key].get('name')`. Иначе будет падать.

Comment: У автора `str(json['person1']['name'])` возвращает `None`, значит не будет падать и этот вариант.